# Kivy Video does not work on Mac: Error loading texture test.mp4

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on video player app on kivy, but it does not load videos. The code is below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from kivy.uix.video import Video

video = Video(source='test.mp4')
```

and the message is as follows:

```
[WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (14 instead of 21)
[WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/chainedman/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-01-29_14.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/Users/chainedman/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.3.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/Users/chainedman/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.3.1/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: null(['video_ffmpeg', 'video_ffpyplayer'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'2.1 INTEL-10.14.74'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel HD Graphics 5000 OpenGL Engine'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture test.mp4
```

I assume that `[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: null(['video_ffmpeg', 'video_ffpyplayer'] ignored)`may be problematic. I installed ffpyplayer but it does not work. Also I found ffmpeg package in pip and have once installed, but got an error like 'ffmpeg has no attribute ".FFVideo."' Is it mentioning another package FFVideo? I found it in pip as well, but it seems so old that it is hard to install.

Any idea will help. Thanks!

Comment: I get the same error on Ubuntu, but the `Video` works in spite of the error, Have you tried actually using it in an `App`?

Comment: Yes, I tried in `App,` but still it doesn't work, just opening a window with no widget (I didn't put any widgets other than the video) and returning the same error.